# Why my action extension do not show up in notes app

Tags: ios, swift

I have already add NSExtensionActivationRule like:

```
NSExtensionActivationSupportsText = true
```

but I still can't find my action extension in Notes app like this:

[Notes app do not show my action extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5kJ5.jpg)

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most important is the fact that the `NSExtensionActivationRule` is a dictionary. The way to use the dictionary is described as follows:

> The value for each key is an integer that specifies the maximum number of files of the corresponding data type that your extension can handle

In your case, this would manifest itself as:

```
NSExtensionActivationRule: {
    NSExtensionActivationSupportsText: 1
}
```

If you still can't see it, I would recommend opening `More` and making sure it is not there. Extensions need to be activated in that menu before they appear.